# get name attribute (having square bracket) of focused element using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have form having multiple inputs and select boxes (used https://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/). I'm running a specific code when a specific key is pressed. So in that code first I try to get the name attribute of focused element. It works perfects for elements having a simple name like `name="xyz"` i.e. plain text.

The element is inside table cell "td".

But when element contains name having a square bracket in it like `name="abc_xyz[]"`, the code fails. It returns undefined.
Also, the element is "select" and doesn't have an ID but have class.

So I have tried using class but it has not worked.
As class is like `class="xyz_abc selectized"`

Here is what I have tried so far.

```
var focusedName = $(':focus').attr('name');
var focusedName = $(':focus').attr('class').split(' ');
```

I have tried .slice(0,-2) and .prop() method also.

for example:

```
var focusedName = $(':focus').attr('name').slice(0,-2);
var focusedName = $(':focus').prop('name');
var focusedName = $(':focus').attr('name');
```

HTML sample:

```
<td>
<select name="item_group1[]" class="item_group1 selectized" tabindex="-1" style="display: none;"><option value="10" selected="selected">BBBBBBBBBGROUP1</option>
</select>
<div class="selectize-control item_group1 single">
<div class="selectize-input items has-options full has-items">
<div class="item" data-value="10">BBBBBBBBBGROUP1</div>
<input type="select-one" autocomplete="off" tabindex="" style="width: 4px; opacity: 0; position: absolute; left: -10000px;">
</div>
<div class="selectize-dropdown single item_group1" style="display: none; visibility: visible; width: 294px; top: 24px; left: 0px;">
<div class="selectize-dropdown-content">
<div class="option selected" data-selectable="" data-value="12">AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAa</div>
<div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="8">AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</div>
<div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="9">AAAAAAAAAAGROUP1</div>
<div class="option selected" data-selectable="" data-value="10">BBBBBBBBBGROUP1</div>
<div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="7">DADADWDSDS</div>
<div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="11">GROUP1GROUP1</div>
</div></div></div>
</td>
```

So please help me solve this issue. Why it returns undefined for name on select element. Thank You.

Comment: This appears to be an XY question as you're asking about retrieving the name without the square brackets instead of showing the logic which is being broken by the brackets. If you can edit the question to show that code you'll get more effective answers. Also note that a sample of the HTML would help too

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan sorry, I forgot to mention that the element is inside table cell td. I think it might have issue while getting focuse element which is inside table cell. This works perfect for elements which have plain text in name and out of table cell. By the way thanks for your help.